# Nuxtjs - How to redirect an old url to an external url

Tags: javascript, vue.js, redirect, nuxt.js, subdomain

I have qr codes that have been published with an old url. I need to redirect that old url to a new external url. I have just revamped this project by incorporating Nuxtjs. I have tried using the redirect middleware, but no success. Can somebody help me?

I want my old url, 'example.io/guestbooklet/1' to redirect to 'https://dashboard.example.io/guestbooklet/1'

**middleware/redirects.js**

```
export default function(req, res, next) {
    const redirects = [
      {
        from: "/guestbooklet/:property_id", 
        to: "https://dashboard.example.io/guestbooklet/:property_id"
      }
    ]
    const redirect = redirects.find((r) => r.from === req.url)
    console.log('Redirecting', redirect)
    if (redirect) {
      res.writeHead(301, { Location: redirect.to })
      res.end()
    } else {
      next()
    }
  }
```

**nuxt.config.js**

```
serverMiddleware: [
        '~/middleware/redirects.js'
  ],
```

Comment: What if you create a page like /guestbooklet/_id.vue and call window.location.replace("https://dashboard.example.io/guestbooklet/" + this.$route.params.id); in your mounted hook?

Comment: I did get that working, but I just figured there might be a better way to redirect with no latency. I know the vue-router package has a way to easily redirect, but have never done it with Nuxtjs.